# How can I convert my mp3s to an iTunes-compatible format?

Tags: windows, itunes, mp3

I've got a bunch of mp3s that iTunes just won't read or import. As far as I can tell they are just regular MP3s but obviously there is something iTunes doesn't like about them.

After a bit of research, it seems the most likely reason is that they are somehow the "wrong format" and iTunes can't get its tiny brain round them. They play perfectly fine in VLC (obviously), QuickTime and Windows Media Player.

Is there a way to "normalize" the data in some way, without losing any quality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been in the same boat before. Used [Winamp](http://www.winamp.com/) to convert it into an `aac` file. Else [MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/) or [SUPER](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html) will also do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. I've used SUPER before for video, and despite the terrible website and program interface, it got the job done.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If it's a MP3 in a container (e.g. a RIFF or Ogg container) then it can be done with no loss of fidelity. If it's another codec that just happens to have a file extension of ".mp3" then there's a very good chance that quality will be reduced since it will require transcoding. In either case, VLC can convert the audio for you. `Media` | `Convert/Save...` will allow you to select the files and convert them to the proper codec and container.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, but you could just try renaming the file extension to something else that itunes reads.  I've had a few files that somehow got the wrong extension and therefore couldn't be opened in some programs.